# Java - return 2 values (String array)

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have this java code and i want to return 2 values and then use them in main() or in other functions. Some help please. TX :

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class URLReader {

public  String[] functie(String x) throws Exception
{
    URL oracle = new URL(x);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));
    String inputLine=null;
    StringBuffer theText = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            theText.append(inputLine+"\n");

    String html = theText.toString();
    in.close();

    String[] tds = StringUtils.substringsBetween(html, "<tr>", "</tr>");

    String[] tds2 = StringUtils.substringsBetween(tds[1], "href=\"/module/gallery", "\"><img");
    String[] tds3 = StringUtils.substringsBetween(tds[1], "src='/redx_tools/mb_image.php", "' border='1'");

    return ???

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String x = new String("http://www.wippro.at/module/gallery/index.php?limitstart=0&picno=0&gallery_key=59");

    URLReader s = new URLReader();
    for (String st : s.functie(x))
    {
        System.out.println(st);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you build your strings?  if `a` and `b` are the String objects you want to return, you can build a String array to return like this:

```
return new String[] {a, b};
```

You've built three String arrays in your code:  `tds`, `tds2`, and `tds3`.  All of them could be returned in a big array like this:

```
String[] retArray = new String[tds.length+tds2.length+tds3.length];
System.arrayCopy(tds,  0, retArray, 0, tds.length);
System.arrayCopy(tds2, 0, retArray, tds.length, tds2.length);
System.arrayCopy(tds3, 0, retArray, tds.length+tds2.length, tds3.length);
return retArray
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many solutions to your question, however the simplest one I can think of is to create a list containing multiple values and return the entire list like this:

public class URLReader {

```
public List<String[]> functie(String x) throws Exception
{
    ...

    final String[] tds = StringUtils.substringsBetween(html, "<tr>", "</tr>");

    String[] tds2 = StringUtils.substringsBetween(tds[1], "href=\"/module/gallery", "\"><img");
    String[] tds3 = StringUtils.substringsBetween(tds[1], "src='/redx_tools/mb_image.php", "' border='1'");

    List<String[]> substrList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    substrList.add(tds);
    substrList.add(tds2);
    substrList.add(tds3);

    return substrList;

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String x = new String("http://www.wippro.at/module/gallery/index.php?limitstart=0&picno=0&gallery_key=59");

    URLReader s = new URLReader();
    for (String[] st : s.functie(x))
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(st));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you, but how i use (print) as an string array only "tds2"?

Comment: `for (String st : s.functie(x).get(1))
         System.out.println(st);`

Comment: you got the right idea, but may I ask what are you trying to achieve with this code? I generally do not recommend coding practices like these (s.functie(x).get(1))

Comment: I want to get some images and descriptions.

Answer (score 2):

Ive asked myself that question several times in the past. My most recent way of doing this is to return a Map. Its the most flexible way of returning several values. Let's say you need to return a String, an int and maybe even a class. With a Map (not using generics) you can return all these. I think this is better than declaring an inner class that would only serve as a data container.

Comment: this is a good idea.  Someone reading the code knows exactly what's going on because of explicit casting (if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Just return a Vector with 2 entries :-)

Comment: Vector is considered deprecated and ArrayList should be used in most cases.

Comment: I use Vector when i want it to work on all JVM's no matter how old they are. Synchronization-overhead is clearly not an issue when inserting only 2 entries (or even 2 dozen).

Answer (score -1):

Looks like what you're doing is parsing out the link an image points to, along with some properties.  A couple of observations:

1. Instead of returning these values in some anonymous collection
   (array, list, whatever), consider constructing a class which will
   hold your values.  Something like `ImageProperties` below.  This
   solves your need to return "multiple" values, and simplifies all
   your later programming.
2. As written, you're hardcoding a dependency on the specific format of 
   the table contents and the img tags you will be processing.  If anything 
   changes (like the order of tags), you'll break.  Consider doing something 
   a bit more flexible in your parsing.

---

```
 class ImageProperties {
   String imageHref;         // This gets what you are putting in td2
   String imageProperties;   // This gets what you are putting in td3
   // I assume you know how to create a constructor.
 }
```

Then, of course, your "functie" (needs a better name, of course) would return an instance of ImageProperties:

```
 public ImageProperties[] functie(String url) throws Exception    {
    URL oracle = new URL(url);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));
    String inputLine=null;
    StringBuffer theText = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            theText.append(inputLine+"\n");
    String html = theText.toString();
    in.close();
    // TODO: This parsing needs work to make it more change-resistant
    String[] tds = StringUtils.substringsBetween(html, "<tr>", "</tr>");
    String[] tds2 = StringUtils.substringsBetween(tds[1], "href=\"/module/gallery", "\"><img");
    String[] tds3 = StringUtils.substringsBetween(tds[1], "src='/redx_tools/mb_image.php", "' border='1'");
    if (tds2.length != tds3.length) {
       throw new ToldYouThisNeededChange();
    } else {
       ImageProperties[] ret = new ImageProperties[tds2.length];
       for (int ii=0; ii < tds2.length; ii++) {
          ImageProperties props = new ImageProperties(tds2[ii], tds3[ii]);
       }
       return ret;
     }
 }
```

Comment: cannot find symbol
    symbol  : constructor ImageProperties(java.lang.String[],java.lang.String[])
    location: class ImageProperties
        return new ImageProperties(tds2, tds3);
               ^

Comment: functie is declared to return a `String[]`, not a `ImageProperties`. The member variables of the new class you suggested should probably be arrays of Strings rather than String objects, unless you think the constructor is going to do something clever to coerce the arguments to String objects. (plus what @Bogdan said -- you've no constructor but use one)

Comment: @Atreys.  Thanks, I missed the change of the return type.  Disagree about arrays of strings - original 'functie' only finds one of each. As to the constructor, I also skipped a toString method and hashcode and equals.  Again, though, thanks for the catch on the return type.

Comment: @CPerkins, The original functie from the OP has `return ???` at the end of it.  The question isn't too clear about what it's supposed to do.  from your code it is obvious that tds2 is an Array, as is tds3.  As they are fed to the constructor, it seems plausible that they are going to have something to do with the data stored by the class.  The confusion deepens.  Is it an assumption that the tds2 and 3 arrays only have one item each?

Comment: Good point. I looked at them and misread `substringsBetween` as `substringBetween`.  Will rewrite.